# How to parse onclick javascript event parameter using MSHTML?

Tags: html, mshtml

I need to extract the javascript call in the onlick event defined in the following markup:

```
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick='javascript:start("a", "b", "code");'>Click Here</div></div>
```

This is what I want to extract from onclick as a text string:
'javascript:start("a", "b", "code");'

I am a novice at using MSHTML and this is what I tried so far and I am getting nowhere. Maybe there is a better way to do this?

```
foreach (mshtml.IHTMLElement elm in (IHTMLElementCollection)doc.body.all)
{
    if (elm.getAttribute("onclick", 0) != null)
    {
        if (elm.getAttribute("onclick", 0).ToString().Contains("javascript:start"))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Found!");
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Just check the outerHTML of the element.  elm.outerHTML.ToLower().Contains("javascript:start")

Answer (score 1):

The onclick attribute should not contain "javascript:" at all.  It doesn't accept a javascript: URL as its value.  It should just contain javascript expressions.  (Although, if you do include "javascript:", then it is just treated by the scripting engine as a label with no adverse effects).

i.e.
`<p onclick="alert('hello');">This is correct</p>`

`<p onclick="javascript:alert('hello');">This is not ideal.</p>`

So then assuming the markup being parsed does this correctly, then your code above should not check for the inclusion of the string "javascript:".  It should just be:

`if (elm.getAttribute("onclick", 0).ToString().Contains("start"))`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get this data is through the .getAttribute() function:

```
If oHTMLDivElement.hasAttribute("onclick") then
    Debug.Print oHTMLDivElement.getAttribute("onclick")
End If
```

This assumes that 'oHTMLDivElement' is an MSHTML.HTMLDivElement object.